# Arithmetic operations of complex numbers in c

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2015

I'm interested in how I can perform arithmetic operations of complex numbers in the c language using a standard library the win32. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    _Dcomplex a;
    _Dcomplex b = 2. + 3. * _Complex_I;
    _Dcomplex c = a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand, the C99 standard is not supported by Microsoft. How do I bypass the restrictions?
Thanks

Comment: Hand roll your own complex class

Comment: 'a' is uninitialized. Refer this for more details: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/Complex_I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, earlier Microsoft was not eager to provide C99 libraries support because of its comparatively smaller userbase and pain in porting mordern gcc based code to MSVC. It's a matter of priority.

But, on the demand of developers, they have implemented many C99 libraries in Visual Studio 2013 and above that are mentioned here :

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013/

So, the code in C can be written as :

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* Standard Library of Input and Output */
#include <complex.h>    /* Standard Library of Complex Numbers */

int main() {

double complex z1 = 1.0 + 3.0 * I;
double complex z2 = 1.0 - 4.0 * I;

printf("Initial values: Z1 = %.2f + %.2fi \nZ2 = %.2f %+.2fi\n", creal(z1), cimag(z1), creal(z2), cimag(z2));

double complex sum = z1 + z2;
printf("Sum: Z1 + Z2 = %.2f %+.2fi\n", creal(sum), cimag(sum));

double complex diff = z1 - z2;
printf("Diff: Z1 - Z2 = %.2f %+.2fi\n", creal(difference), cimag(difference));

double complex product = z1 * z2;
printf("Product: Z1 x Z2 = %.2f %+.2fi\n", creal(product), cimag(product));

double complex quotient = z1 / z2;
printf("Quotient: Z1 / Z2 = %.2f %+.2fi\n", creal(quotient), cimag(quotient));

double complex conjugate = conj(z1);
printf("Conjugate of Z1 = %.2f %+.2fi\n", creal(conjugate), cimag(conjugate));

return 0;
```

}

functions like cos(), exp() and sqrt() must be replaced with their complex forms, e.g. ccos(), cexp(), csqrt() and they work just fine.

Other workaround could be to completely scrape the MS compiler and use intel compiler(which is more enlightened) which works in Visual C.

A more sensible approach is to move over to Intel CC or gcc, and use Eclipse for your programming environment. Portability of code across Windows-Linux-Solaris-AIX-etc is usually important and that is not at all supported by MS tools, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To use the gcc compiler, do my need to install another library?

Comment: @ViteDecorum You can check this [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) to help you to install gcc compiler. You just need to download the source and then install it.

Comment: I know that the C99 for Windows library is unfinished. I need to bypass the constraint. Perhaps there is a source to work around the limitation, without installing `gcc` for windows or `gnuwin32`?

Comment: I don't think that there could be any other way to use those libraries than to use any other compiler other than of Microsoft. Even then, if you want so, you can implement the required functions​ yourself and save them in a header file.

Comment: I wanted to test the algorithms for the performance of the C vs C ++ language based on the `libsdl` library, for the windows platform. But unfortunately, for MS there was a problem of support of standard C99. I'll look at what I can think of to move some of the implementation code of the `glibc` library for use the `gcc` compiler under the windows platform. Thank you